# Zend_Form_Element_Hash random failures

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a load of ZF1 salted hash elements in various forms on my site and 99% of the time they work fine but occasionally they fail. This usually seems to happen after a redirect but not within the redirect hop. The form is created after the redirect in a separate action so I don't understand why the redirect would be affecting it. The forms that fail are generating their tokens correctly, they just don't match after the POST and validation.

Any ideas?

Hash element below:

```
$token = $this->createElement(
    'hash', 
    'token', 
    array('timeout' => 1440)
);

$token->setSalt($config->csrf->salt)
      ->addErrorMessage('The session for this form has timed out.');

$this->addElement($token);
```

Comment: Sounds like a segmentation fault? What do the apache logs show?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. That was one of the first things I checked. I doubt it's a segfault as I can reproduce the issue on multiple servers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just don't match"?

Comment: The tokens are different before and after the POST which is why an error is thrown. It's as if the hash is being regenerated at some point when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I would agree the hash is being regenerated. I would add some debugging to the `setSalt()` method and see when and who is calling him. I bet you will find your culprit. Too bad it sounds like it is difficult to reproduce. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael. See my answer for how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was due to token naming. I had a standard hash element named 'token' that was added to all forms. I changed the code so that the token name was prepended with the form name so rather than 'token' they are now 'loginformtoken', etc.

I'm still not sure if this was due to an issue in my code due to redirects or whether ZF uses an internal 'token' session anywhere (the word token seems to be fairly heavily used in the ZF source code) that was causing a conflict.

Nevertheless, using unique hash ids seems to be the way forward and I'll be following this standard in the future.

**Edit:**

This was my fault completely for not reading the manual:

> The name of the hash element should be unique. We recommend using the salt option for the element- two hashes with same names and different salts would not collide.

I had a default salt and the same hash name so no wonder I was having problems.